# Renaming error for existing file

Tags: java, file

I want to rename an existing file name. But if user entering a name and this named file created before,  program will give an error. Like " New file name is existed ! " How can i do this.

```
            else if (noteNameSplited[0].equals("rename")) {

            File file = new File(noteNameSplited[1]+".ncat");

            if(!file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File does not exist !");
            }
            if(file.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Enter the new note name");
                String data=scan.nextLine();
                if(data.contains(" ")){
                    System.out.println("Invalid note name for renaming. It contains ' '.");
                }else{
                    File file2 = new File(data+".ncat");
                    file.renameTo(file2);
                }

            }
```

Comment: `if (file.exists())` should be `else`

Comment: can you adapt to my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Get from ser the new name and do:

```
File f = new File(newFile);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // do something
}
```

---

## Your final snippet can look like:

```
File f = new File(newFile);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    System.out.println("A file with that name already exist...");
    System.out.println("Enter the new note name");
}else{
    System.out.println("Renaming file...");
    oldFile.renameTo(f);
}
```

Comment: ı tried to adapt my code but i did not. can you adapt over my code ?

Comment: I updated the answer 13 min ago, did you try that version??

Comment: string from scanner. for example rename stack. noteNameSplitted[0] = rename this is command other one is note name.